# How to obtain extrinsic matrix from ARKit camera?

Tags: ios, swift, camera, augmented-reality, arkit

I want to convert the pixel coordinate into real world coordinate. And I found that the ARKit API provide a function in `ARCamera` call `viewMatrix()`

> Returns a transform matrix for converting from world space to camera
>   space

It this function can obtain extrinsic matrix for the camera?

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
self.sceneView.session.currentFrame?.camera.transform
```

> The position and orientation of the camera in world coordinate space.

[`.transform` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arcamera/2866108-transform)

You can directly extract the `eulerAngles` from this, but will have to parse the translation yourself.

How come you manually want to project pixels into world positions? (The transform alone isn't going to help you there obviously).

Comment: It is because I want to create the object into far away position. hitTest method only allow me to create the object inside detected feature point area. Do you have any suggestion to implement far away object creation?

Comment: @SinLok Did you find out how to get in/extrinsic matrix for the camera?